# Spring-boot - application properties configuration for log file per level

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, slf4j

I'm trying to get separate log file based on log levels, for eg. separate file for debug, info, error

My current configuration in application.properties file only keeps in single file, per date

```
logging.file=myservice-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
logging.level.org.springframework.boot=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

I want separate log files created as

- `myservice-info-20190516.log`
- `myservice-debug-20190516.log`
- `myservice-error-20190516.log`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with [Logback](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging#logback-configuration-logging). You can create different `appenders` for each log level and you're done.

Comment: i looked into this link previously, but I was looking simple way to do through properties file, not xml. It would be great if you please share some .properties file tutorials

Comment: I guess this is actually a limitation of the base Spring Logging system ( not very customizable ). In 90% of the setups that I've seen were using Logback to extend the logging capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Using the recommended and default implementation [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) of the SLF4J façade, you need to configure `appender` for each level of the log.

```
<appender name="debugAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>debug.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>debug-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender> 

<appender name="infoAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>info.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender> 

<appender name="errorAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>error.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

And attach them to the `logger` distinguished by the level:

```
<logger name="com.bla" level="DEBUG" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="debugAppender"/>
</logger>

<logger name="com.bla" level="INFO" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="infoAppender"/>
</logger>

<logger name="com.bla" level="ERROR" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="errorAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: On doing this step, Im seeing same file with same logs with all info, debug, error